# Java BigInteger.and doesn't work for big numbers?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm creating two huge BigIntegers and then anding them. But the and operation doesn't work and instead returns 0. Why?

```
BigInteger aa = new BigInteger("213092840173096182527577008347205670468257779233261101799142588416");
BigInteger bb = new BigInteger("226156424291633194186662097633113218007386784142018559245972777080014766080");
System.out.println(aa.and(bb));
```

> Output: 0

I did a BigInteger 'or' on those two numbers and the 'or' operation worked fine.  Anybody else see the same issue?

Please note that I am using jdk 1.8.

Comment: Although it would be quite random, any possibility that these numbers actually AND to 0?  Improbable but possible.

Comment: Yeah.. my thoughts exactly. I was wondering what is the expected result

Comment: That is it. I was printing the two numbers in dec in the console and got confused. I later managed to print them in hex and saw that they indeed and to zero. My bad!

Answer (score 5):

That is because their `and` is zero! They have no common bits.

Verified using python:

```
>>> x = 226156424291633194186662097633113218007386784142018559245972777080014766
080
>>> y = 213092840173096182527577008347205670468257779233261101799142588416
>>> x & y
0L
>>> bin(x)
'0b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000010010100000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000'
>>> bin(y)
'0b10000001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000
00111000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>>
```

btw, a general comment: before claiming a bug in well tested heavily used libraries, it is prudent to see if you are using it incorrectly/the results are as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The two numbers are decimal and then really and to zero.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to add your own answer, when 1) you can edit your question, and 2) there is already an answer!

Comment: Because we both wrote the answers concurrently. No need to be so picky. Bits are cheap.

Comment: I am not being picky. This site has some rules about questioners answering their own questions, when an edit of the question would suffice instead. Besides, a 9 minute difference is not concurrent.